# In React Native on iOS, is there a way to determine when an app is resumed? Such as an onResume event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to determine when an app is resumed. For instance, when you open the app, press the home button on the device, and then go back into the app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hope you are looking for this. 
[Documentation Here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html)

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    currentAppState: AppStateIOS.currentState,
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  AppStateIOS.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    AppStateIOS.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
_handleAppStateChange: function(currentAppState) {
  this.setState({ currentAppState, });
},
render: function() {
  return (
     <Text>Current state is: {this.state.currentAppState}</Text>
 );
},
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! Btw, it's best to use `AppState` instead of `AppStateIOS` now.

Comment: I had to use `this._handleAppStateChange.bind(this)` for `this` to work in the `_handleAppStateChange` function.

Answer (score 0):

this is listed on the document about AppStateIOS ,if this is not enough, you can use the [send event api](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript)   read the AppDelegate.m in the iOS folder , you know more the life circle about the iOS App.