# React native , detect view screen is Resumed

Tags: android, react-native, resume, onpause

How to detect in react native that alert box or new screen is get dismissed and back screen is get resumed to the user.

which method will provide this kind call back ?

### example :in android if alert box get dismissed main screen onResume will provide call back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In React Native on iOS, is there a way to determine when an app is resumed? Such as an onResume event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905840/in-react-native-on-ios-is-there-a-way-to-determine-when-an-app-is-resumed-such)

Comment: that is used for app state like when the app page going to be mount and when system have finish that page , what i want is simple that is that page get visible to user , what i want is like  example of onResume  method that i have described